# Is there a way to give multiple file locations for renaming files?

Tags: python-3.x

I want a program to rename subtitles file as same as the movie file, which are located in different folders and sub-folders.

What I have done:

1. Imported `os`, `re`, and `shutil` modules.
2. Made a `for` loop to iterate through a directory and return files/folders inside of a parent folder.

```py
for foldername, subfoldername, filename in os.walk('E:\Movies'):
```

3. This loop will iterate through the `E:\Movies` folder and assume a list of sub folders and files.
4. To check whether file is a subtitle file, inside of for loop,

```py
if filename.endswith('(.srt|.idx|.sub)'):
```

5. How do i give multiple paths and new names in the single second argument?

```
os.rename(filename,'')
```

Comment: You need to post actual code, a description of steps is not the way this site works.

Comment: Hello David, I haven't written a full code and that's what just I came up with. I am still trying to figure out the logic for the given problem. But I understood your point and would take care from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to give multiple paths and new names in the second argument?
The Code you shared does the following :

```
Loop through the directory tree.
For each filename in directory :   
    If file is subtitle file :   
        Rename file to movie file present some directory
```

In the last step you are not renaming all the files at once. You are doing them one at a time.
`os.rename(src,dest)`
Accepts two arguments only, the `src` filename and `dest` filename.
So for your case you will have to loop again through all the files in the directory, match the name of subtitle file with movie file, and then rename the subtitle file.
Try Something Like :

```
for foldername,subfoldername,filename in os.walk('E:\Movies'):
    if filename.endswith('(.srt|.idx|.sub)'):
        for folder2,subfolder2,moviename in os.walk('E:\Movies'):
            # We don't want to match the file with itself
            if(moviename != filename):
            # You would have to think of your matching logic here
            # How would you know if that subtitle is of that particular movie
            # eg. if subtitle is of form 'a_good_movie.srt' you can split on '_' and check if all words are present in movie name
```

**Edit**
After the clarifications in the comments, it seems you want to implement the following :

```
Loop through all Folders in Directory:
    For each Folder in directory, rename all subtitle_files to the Folder name
```

You can do this in Python 3 like this :

```
for folder in next(os.walk(directory))[1]:
    for filename in next(os.walk(directory+folder))[2]:
        if(filename.endswith(('.srt','.idx','.sub'))):
            os.rename(filename,directory);
```

`os.walk()` returns a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). You can access the value of `os.walk()` generator as such in python 3 :

```
next(os.walk('C:\startdir'))[0] # returns 'C:\startdir'
next(os.walk('C:\startdir'))[1] # returns list of directories in 'C:\startdir'
next(os.walk('C:\startdir'))[2] # returns list of files in 'C:\startdir'
```

For python 2 you can call `os.walk().next()[]` with same return values

Comment: Actually my task is that there are multiple movie folders with video file and subtitle file, in one parent 'Movie' folder. Eg inside Movies I have subfolders(avengers, bad boys, etc). Each of these movie subfolders have video and subtitle file. The subtitle files in each of these are in different format. Some of them are seperated by underscore or by different letters. I need to match all these subtitle name formats and change them with same name as movie's foldername. The reason for giving multiple paths in 2nd argument was because there are multiple different movie folders (mov1,mov2).

Comment: @milap updated the answer, and as i said, you cannot give multiple paths for the rename function. Also, you should have included these details in the original question...